# What did Pol Pot expect to gain from his raid against Ba Chuc Vietnam in April 1978?

Tags: vietnam, indochina

This was a major raid by Khmer Rouge forces over the Vietnamese border, resulting in the deaths of over 3000 Vietnamese.

For more information and details, please see:

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_Chúc_massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ba_Ch%C3%BAc_massacre)

https://youtu.be/Ei9W8hW29GQ

Was Pol Pot that foolish enough to think that he could carry out such a raid without a severe response from Vietnam? It turned out that this raid was a major catalyst leading to Vietnam’s invasion of Cambodia and subsequent overthrow of the Khmer Rouge.

The only logical explanation for this raid that I can think of is that Pol Pot was using Vietnamese border raids as a way of distracting the militant energy of his subordinates instead of letting this militancy result in a potential coup against himself. If this was the case, this got out of hand quickly. Or this was a decision made by a local Khemer Rouge commander that Pol Pot was not aware of.

In any case, this raid would later set a lot in motion two invasions (Vietnam vs Cambodia and China vs Vietnam) and years of insurgency in Cambodia.

Comment: Don't discount the most obvious explanation: Pol Pot was bananas.

Answer (score 9):

This was not an isolated incident, but rather a part (see, e.g., [Thổ Chu Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%E1%BB%95_Chu_Islands#History)) of a "creeping aggression".

Consider

1. Khemer Rouge were allies of China
2. Vietnam was allied with USSR
3. USSR & China were [unfriendly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Soviet_split)
4. Cambodia & Vietnam were neighbors and, as is common among neighbors, traditionally hostile to each other and had territorial issues.

The only real question is not *why* but *why now*.
This is explained by the general cooling off of the relationships between China and Vietnam, following the end of the Vietnam war.